# How do I mock azure mobile services in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, azure-mobile-services

I'm writing an AngularJs front end to an Azure Mobile Services backend and scratching my head wondering the 'angular way' to mock the backend in my tests.

Initial thoughts are that I could create a lookalike service that simply returns expected values but I'm used to using a mocking framework like Moq in my C sharp work to ease the burden.

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accesing this services using $http or resource?

Two options:
    - You can use a mocking framework like Sinon (we have combined it with jasmine for an angularjs based app, mocking $http request).

http://sinonjs.org/docs/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK-Z0oEdE4Y

http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/28/mocking-requests-with-mocha-chai-and-sinon/

```
- You can use angularmocks and for some given url's return harcoded values.
```

Comment: Braulio, thanks for the reply.  I'm accessing via the [microsoft javascript sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services), and also have the option of going direct to the http rest api.  Sinonjs looks like it could do the job very nicely so I'll have a play with that and see how it goes, thanks for the details.